# Discriminator support in Salesforce External Service

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex, external-services

I have an ExternalService in Salesforce from an OpenAPI 3.0 spec. We have multiple object types that we can get which are all nested under the same path for the GET request (eg. `ExampleSubObject1` and `ExampleSubObject2`).

When calling the GET request from a flow or Apex, I get the following error:

```
Error Occurred: Callout failed for invocable action Kooltra::ExampleAPI.getExampleObject. The polymorphic object ExampleAPI_ExampleObject does not accept ExampleSubObject1 as the type discriminator for service ExampleAPI
```

I can share all of the OpenAPI spec if required but I will provide the highlights here.

Under paths, for the GET we have:

```
   "/v1/example_objects/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "getExampleObject",
        "summary": "Get example object",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "path",
            "name": "id",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "security": [
          {
            "ExampleObjectOAuth2": [
              "api.example.com/example_object:read"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ExampleObject"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

For the create and update operations, we would hit a path with the type included (eg. `/v1/example_objects/sub1`).

As seen above, when successful, the GET request returns an `ExampleObject`. Here is the schema for the `ExampleObject` which uses a discriminator from a `type` field on the sub objects:

```
      "ExampleObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "type",
          "mapping": {
            "ExampleSubObject1": "#/components/schemas/ExampleSubObject1",
            "ExampleSubObject2": "#/components/schemas/ExampleSubObject2"
          }
        },
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ExampleSubObject1"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ExampleSubObject2"
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
```

I know my setup is correct for callouts because I'm able to do creates and updates. Also, this flow works if I remove the discriminator from the `ExampleObject` like so:

```
      "ExampleObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ExampleSubObject1"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ExampleSubObject2"
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
```

I've been working through docs for the last couple of days but haven't been able to resolve this. I am curious if maybe Salesforce does not properly support the discriminator tag in OpenAPI 3.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!